# ¿Se puede posicionar componentes en un panel con layout en los pixeles que uno quiera?O los layouts no te dejan elegir donde poner los componentes?

Tags: java

```
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());this.add(panel);

JButton boton=new JButton("Hola");
panel.add(boton);
```

Cuando lo ejecuto el boton me aparece arriba de todo,¿se puede poner en el medio de la pantalla sin usar otro layout?
[image: codigo]
[image: Imagen del boton el cual me gustaria reposicionar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende del layout utilizado, un JPanel o un JFrame utilizará dicho layout para colocar el componente añadido en un sitio o en otro, con sus respectivos métodos.

El layout por defecto tanto de JPanel como de JFrame es el FlowLayout. Dicho layout coloca los componentes uno al lado de otro de forma centrada en la parte superior, con el mínimo de espacio ocupado para cada uno (por ejemplo, un botón ocupará lo mínimo para almacenar el texto que contenga). Cuando no quepan más por el ancho del JFrame o del JPanel continuará añadiendo componentes en la siguiente línea, un poco más abajo.

Se puede anular este layout estableciendo otro layout, o un valor nulo (setLayout(null)).

Cuando hay una falta de layout (setLayout(null)) es cuando se pueden colocar los componentes utilizando las coordenadas X e Y.

Lo bueno de esta disposición es que se ponen los componentes donde uno quiera.

Lo malo:

- No atienden a redimensiones, si se reduce la ventana, los componentes pueden llegar a quedarse fuera, y no verse.
- Cuando son muchos componentes hay que ir controlando a cada momento donde cabe 1 y donde cabe otro.

En muchas más ocasiones es preferible una conjunción de layouts y de JPanel. No olvidemos que se pueden colocar varios JPanel, uno sobre otro, de distintos tamaños. Por ejemplo, en un JPanel con un gridlayout puede haber un JPanel por cada sección de ese GridLayout, y cada uno de esos JPanel puede tener establecido su propio layout. Y en muchas ocasiones esta conjunción de paneles con sus respectivos layouts suele ser preferible que poner los componentes por coordenadas. Ya que suelen acomodarse mejor al tamaño de la ventana, y a cada cambio de tamaño de ventana siguen acomodándose.

Si en el buscador de la API de java buscamos "layout" nos saldrán un listado de todas las clases cuyo nombre contenga "layout" (que son todos los layouts) además de otras clases y métodos. Es una buena forma de localizar todos los layouts existentes en la API.

Por otra parte, si ninguno de estos layouts ni una conjunción de ellos (con distintos JPanel) siempre es posible construir nuestro propio Layout.

Comment: Si @Kritik , es lo que le intento explicar mas abajo en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Si que se puede, mira como se hace:

```js
etiqueta1 = new JLabel("Nombre: ");
etiqueta1.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 50);
etiqueta1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
panel.add(etiqueta1);
```

El metodo [setBounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) es el que coloca el objeto en la posicion deseada del panel y le da el tamaño al mismo tiempo.

Comment: No me funciona hermano,lo que tengo entendido es que solo se puede usar con el layout null,no se si entendi bien.Mi panel tiene un flowlayout,al poner el setBounds no modifica ni el tamaño ni la posicion.Tengo entenido que para cambiarle el tamaño tengo que usar el setPreferedSize.Como te puedo adjuntar una imagen para mostrarte?

Comment: Exactamente....colocar los componentes en un panel solamente funcionara en caso de que su layout sea null por que si no es así no tiene sentido, el layout lo que hace es ordenar los componentes de diferentes formas automáticamente pero si ese mismo layout esta a null entonces si te permite colocarlos tu donde necesites. No se si me he explicado correctamente. ¿Me entiendes?

Comment: Entiendo,el tema es como pongo el boton ese en el medio de la pantalla?teniendo en cuenta que tengo el flowlayout.O no se puede?tendria que usar un gridlayout o un borderlayout?

Comment: No....tendrias que poner el layout a null....para colocar el boton donde tu quisieras con el setBounds indicandole las coordenadas  y el tamaño.

Comment: Claro,pero el problema es que si yo agrando o achico la pantalla no se redimensiona y me gustaria que se redimensione

Comment: Si necesitas redimensionar si o si, debes usar un layout de los disponibles perdiendo la capacidad de colocar los componentes donde tu desees. También puedes hacer un layout null colocar los componentes donde desees y no permitir el redimensionado, no se si esto servirá para tu aplicación.

Comment: Perfecto,muchas gracias.Vos decis que esta bien usar layouts si o si,o depende el caso se puede evaluar la posibilidad de ponerlos en null?

Comment: Si....mas o menos digo eso, exactamente digo, si puedes prescindir del redimensionado usa layout null y coloca tu mismo los componentes donde te interese pero si tienes que tener obligatoriamente redimensionado pues no queda otra que usar un layout de los existentes perdiendo la capacidad de colocar tu los componentes ya que en este ultimo caso se recolocan automaticamente.